# OpenCV Key point matcher matches to the wrong areas in Python for certificate template and image

Tags: python, image, opencv, keypoint

I was using the code given on [this site](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/08/31/image-alignment-and-registration-with-opencv/) to align a photograph of my certificate to a 'template' i created by converting my pdf certificate to png and deleting my name, candidate id and certification date. Sadly it key point matches the wrong areas (click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2e6Df.png) for image), specifically matching my name, canditate ID and the date to areas in the certificate when it shouldn't. Oddly enough it works fine when I key point match the photograph with itself (i.e.: without deleting my name, date etc.)

I have tried using different matchers including sift and the brute force matcher but still all result in the same problem. Does anyone know why this may be happening and is there anything I can try to overcome this?

Thanks :)

Here is the code that I am using:

```
# import the necessary packages
#import numpy as np
import imutils
import cv2

def align_images(image, template, maxFeatures=500, keepPercent=0.2,
    debug=True):
    # convert both the input image and template to grayscale
    imageGray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    templateGray = cv2.cvtColor(template, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # use ORB to detect keypoints and extract (binary) local
    # invariant features
    orb = cv2.ORB_create(maxFeatures)
    (kpsA, descsA) = orb.detectAndCompute(imageGray, None)
    (kpsB, descsB) = orb.detectAndCompute(templateGray, None)

    # match the features
    method = cv2.DESCRIPTOR_MATCHER_BRUTEFORCE_HAMMING
    matcher = cv2.DescriptorMatcher_create(method)
    matches = matcher.match(descsA, descsB, None)

    # sort the matches by their distance (the smaller the distance,
    # the "more similar" the features are)
    matches = sorted(matches, key=lambda x:x.distance)

    # keep only the top matches
    keep = int(len(matches) * keepPercent)
    matches = matches[:keep]
    # Extract location of good matches
    points1 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    points2 = np.zeros((len(matches), 2), dtype=np.float32)
    matches = cv2.drawMatches(image, kpsA,template,kpsB,matches,None)
    matches = imutils.resize(matches, width = 1000)
    cv2.imshow("Matched Keypoints",matches)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    for i, match in enumerate(matches):
        points1[i, :] = kpsA[match.queryIdx].pt
        points2[i, :] = kpsB[match.trainIdx].pt

     # Find homography
    H, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)


    # use the homography matrix to align the images
    (h, w) = template.shape[:2]
    aligned = cv2.warpPerspective(image, H, (w, h))

    # return the aligned image
    return aligned

image = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Soffie\Documents\GrayceAssignments\certificate_scanner\certif_image2.jpg")
template = cv2.imread(r"C:\Users\Soffie\Documents\GrayceAssignments\certificate_scanner\certificate_template.png")
aligned = align_images(image, template)

aligned = imutils.resize(aligned,width =700)
template = imutils.resize(template,width = 700)
stacked = np.hstack([aligned,template])
overlay = template.copy()
output = aligned.copy()
cv2.addWeighted(overlay,0.5,output,0.5,0,output)
cv2.imshow("Image Alignment Stacked",stacked)
cv2.imshow("Image Alignment Overlay", output)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: welcome! where's your findHomography step?

Comment: Hi Christoph, I've added my code in the edit :)

Comment: ignore what matches where. does the result of findHomography look correct?

Comment: To be honest Christoph, I have no idea what it should be. I suppose the only way is to calculate the homography between the two planes (i.e.: between the angled certificate and template) by hand, and see if it matches up? If so, then I will reply in a few days because it might take me a while to work out!

Comment: no. you use findHomography, and then you map the four corners of a rectangle from one view into the other, and you draw them, and then you look at it and judge if that makes sense